# Laravel: Results of paginate() are inconstant across pages

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-query-builder, paginator, laravel-pagination

I am having issue with the paginated results as follows :

**Request :**

```
GET http://localhost:1000/api/v1/public/blog/articles
```

**Response :**

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "article_id": 43
        },
        {
            "article_id": 107
        },
        {
            "article_id": 171
        },
        {
            "article_id": 22
        },
        {
            "article_id": 86
        },
        {
            "article_id": 150
        },
        {
            "article_id": 1
        },
        {
            "article_id": 65
        },
        {
            "article_id": 129
        },
        {
            "article_id": 44
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://localhost:1000/api/v1/public/blog/articles?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 18,
    "last_page_url": "http://localhost:1000/api/v1/public/blog/articles?page=18",
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost:1000/api/v1/public/blog/articles?page=2",
    "path": "http://localhost:1000/api/v1/public/blog/articles",
    "per_page": "10",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 179
}
```

**So, now If I request again in the same link, it shows a different set of articles with different ids.
Also If I go to page=1 or page=2, each and every pages the results are inconstant.**

*I am not sure from where this issue is occuring, 
I want to mention that my other paginated queries are working fine except when I am trying to concat queries for getting a specific result as follows :*

```
$query = DB::query();

// Then Concatenating other queries based on options

// Now Execute The Whole Query
$fetched_articles = $query->paginate(5);
```

It would be helpful, if anyone can describe the paginator flows here with the solution or workarounds.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Are you using group by?

Comment: Yes on many levels according to options while I am concatenating other queries.

Comment: Check laravel documentation, it is mentioned laravel pagination doe snot work well with group by.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes, you are right, Give an answer with the flow of paginator, I am going to try with creating the paginator manually, if it works then thanks to you and my problem is solved solved.

Comment: I have posted the answer as well as a reference link you may like to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Laravel documentation

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

so, you can not use `groupBy` in your query, if you want pagination.

By the way, you can try this [blog post](https://jenssegers.com/57/laravel-pagination-with-grouping-and-eager-loading), may be it will work for you.

Comment: Well, now after creating the paginator manually, the problem is not solved, however, If I only fetch the results with get() method the article ids are also inconstant across the results. When I am removing the groupBy() it is working fine. what should I do now ?

Comment: @FahimUddin if groupBy is not mandatory better to remove it, if you need group by, please post your code, so may be I can get some idea, what is the actual situation.

Comment: So, I solved the issue with groupBy() , and now it is working fine. Thanks to you for pointing out the Laravel Caution Note about the paginator with groupBy and for the referenced blog post.